# If $f$ is continuous and $u \in C^0 \cap H^k$, then is it true that $f(u) \in H^{k}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

What I'm trying to prove is the following:

> Let $B$ be a ball with center in the origin and $u \in H_0^1(B) \cap C^0(\overline B)$ be a solution of
> $$
> -\Delta u = f(|x|, u), u > 0 \quad \text{ in } B, \quad u = 0 \quad \text{ on } \partial B 
> $$
> where $f$ is continuous and locally Lipschitz continuous in the second variable, uniformly with respect to $x$. Then $u \in C^1(B) \cap C^0(\overline B)$.

This should be a standard elliptic regularity argument, but I must be missing something. My idea would be to use the Agmon-Douglis-Nirenberg Theorem to obtain, in a first step, that $u \in H^2(B)$ (since $f(u)$, being continuous up to the boundary, is $L^2$), and then to iterate this until $k$ is so big that we have $u \in C^1(B)$ by the Sobolev embedding. However, I'm not sure if I can do this, since I don't know if the composition $f(u)$ has Sobolev regularity.

My question is, as one can read in the title:

> If $f$ is continuous and $u \in C \cap H^k$, then is it true that $f(u) \in H^{k}$?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Is this just a bootstrap argument?

Comment: Can you specify the unit ball in which dimension?

Comment: Hmm, in the statement of the Theorem it says radius $R$. Regarding the dimension, let us say $N \geq 3$

Comment: All Lipschitz continuous functions on a bounded set are Holder continuous for all $\alpha \leq 1$. So you have local Holder continuity in the second variable (not sure if this is enough to apply the theorems given). And if you're assuming $u$ is continuous on $\bar{B}$ then actually you can just work with $f$'s second variable taking ranges in a bounded set.

Comment: @Chris maybe its just Schauder's Estimates? Then we obtain $u \in C^2(\overline B)$, I wonder why the authors took just first order

Comment: The conditions you gave, imply that $u \in H^2(B)$, so if we are working only on one-dimensional space $(\mathbb{R})$ Rellich–Kondrachov theorem gives the needed conclusion.

Comment: @Chris actually my previous comment is wrong, because $f(|x|, u)$ is not Lipschitz

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso - I'm not too familiar with Schauder's estimates. Do they require $f$ to be Holder continuous in the $x$-variable as well?

Comment: @Chris if you are interested, see Theorem B.1 in Struwe's Variational Methods. It is really for the case $Lu = f(x)$, but we can thing of $g(x) = f(|x|, u(x))$ (after knowing that $u$ is a solution) as being the right-hand side. The problem is that $|g(x) - g(y)| \leq |u(x) - u(y)|$, but we don't knot if $u$ is Lipschitz.